# How to form questions?

Tags: grammaire, questions, possessif

I started learning French (A1 French learner) and I am confused with forming questions in French. For example I want to ask what is your profession?

> *Quelle est ton/votre profession?*

I know that because *profession* is feminine we use *quelle*. Are we using *ton/votre* to show the possession of whom we are talking to the profession?
Is this correct:

> *Quelle profession est tu?*

If it's not correct, why can we say *quel age as tu?*
Question word+ age+ avoir verb + subject? and not apply the same structure when asking about some ones profession?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Quelle est **votre** profession ?* is fine when you use *vous* with the person you talk to but otherwise, that should be *Quelle est **ta** profession ?* profession being a feminine word.

Unlike English, possessive adjectives must agree not only with the person possessing (my, your, his/her, our, your, their) but also with the thing being possessed (mon/ma/mes, ton/ta/tes, son/sa/ses, notre/nos, votre/vos, leur/leurs).

*Quelle profession est tu ?* is odd, you wouldn't ask that to a person but rather to a profession (What profession are you?) You would say instead ***Quelle profession exerces-tu ?***

Note that in actual conversation, you are more likely to hear questions like ***Tu fais quoi dans la vie ?*** or ***Vous faites quoi comme métier ?***

We can ask ***Quel age as-tu ?*** because you kind of "own" an age (literally: What age have you?) this is not the same sentence as "How old are you?" which would be literally "*Combien vieux est-tu ?*" (not idiomatic)